# Oracle: How to Right join a list of values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, list, join

I have a string such as

String ids = "1,2,3,4";

In Oracle database,
Now I can do the select as

```
select a.name from a where id in (ids);
```

The result is if 1,2,4 exist in a table, then will show in list. If 4 not in table, it will not be showed.

I want to do a right join such as

```
select a.name from a right join on a.id in (ids);
```

I hope the result can be

```
1's name
2's name
3's name
null
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result. Are you sure you need a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the following:

```
select d.id, case when IDs.id is not null then name end asname
from yourData d
     left join 
     (
        select trim(regexp_substr('1,2,3', '[^,]+', 1, level)) as id
        from dual
        CONNECT BY instr('1,2,3', ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
     ) IDs
     on d.id = IDs.id
```

This gives:

```
        ID NAME
---------- ------
         1 Name 1
         2 Name 2
         3 Name 3
         4
```

Comment: Thank you. But if the name of 4 is null, the data will not come out.

Comment: The question was not that clear. I just edited to show you a way

Comment: Thank you very much. I change to right join then it is ok now.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `right join`.  `left join` is much more intuitive (keep all rows in the *first* table plus matching rows in the *second*).  In Oracle, you can do:

```
select i.id, a.name
from (select 1 as id from dual union all
      select 2 as id from dual union all
      select 3 as id from dual union all
      select 4 as id from dual
     ) i left join
     a
     on i.id = a.id;
```

There are other ways to generate the list of ids.  This method is relatively simple if you are learning Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what is dual?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Your way is successful. Thank you very much.

Comment: But one problem, if there are too much ids such as 1,2,3,4,5.....,1000. The SQL will be too long. That maybe not a good idea for long string ids.

Comment: @GaryYeung . . . The question is explicitly about 4 ids.  If you have more ids, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Aleksej 's answer solved my problem, thank you.